# How to pass class Form to Class in DLL and inherit class Form

Tags: winforms, inheritance, dll

I have a Class inherit a Form, look like:

```
public class MyLibrary : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
}
```

And I have a Form in another Solution with class Mylibrary, it look like:

```
public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
}
```

How I can do pass the class Form1 to MyLibrary for inherit after referenced to the Solution winform

My mean code look like

```
public class MyLibrary : System.Windows.Forms.Form //<== Form1
{
   //
      Now I can use some class read only in the base Form1 but not in System.Windows.Forms.Form
   //
}
```

Thanks you for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you can add both exe and dll files to your project's references.
Add the relevant file from the project with Form1 to your library's project references, and you shall have access to Form1 in this project (make sure Form1 is a public class).

Comment: thanks you for idea, but what i want to do create a file .dll before file exe, and i can use special method for base Form(Main) in the file .dll after referenced in Project  of file exe